# Calibre ebook viewer - Apply User Stylesheet to Full Screen Mode

Tags: ebook-readers, calibre, css

**How do I apply styles to full screen mode only via the User Stylesheet?**
Specifically, I would like to adjust the `body` style during full screen mode to adjust `margin-left`.

I would like to do this through the User Stylesheet so that changes are applied automatically and I don't have to edit them manually every time I open full screen view.

Currently, I can edit the body tag, but this is applied whether in full screen mode or not.

I feel like there should be some parent element for full screen view so a [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) could be used such as `fullscreen > body`.

Ideas?

**Update:** It looks like the preferences for full screen options, which are limited to max width and max text height, [uses javascript](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/blob/34b0afeca27acfb2f23ab88bdbe0955a5b45bb99/src/calibre/gui2/viewer/documentview.py#L344) to manage the styling.

Any ideas for injecting a parent element that wraps all CSS while `in_fullscreen_mode = True` in `documentview.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste the following in the 'User stylesheet', click ok. Then go to 'Theming' and save the style with whatever name you like. The e-book will display nicely in any screen mode and there are a couple of neat little extras you won't see with other user themes. As with all CSS it can be further altered and tweaked to suit.

```
html {
    background: #e6e9e9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(230, 233, 233) 0%, rgb(216, 221, 221) 100%);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    background: #1f2326;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(225, 225, 225);
    color: #d4d4d4;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding: 2em 2em 4em;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #e4e7e7;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 1.3em;
}

a {
    color: #2196f3;
}

b, strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}

samp {
    display: none;
}

img {
    animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    background: transparent;
    border: 10px solid rgb(145, 143, 140);
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}

@keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
        filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}
```

Comment: this repo has some good themes too. https://github.com/theKAKAN/CalibreCSS . I have also pushed your theme.